# Mongoid: How to model days in a week as embedded documents?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am learning how to use mongo with ruby by using the mongoid gem. I creating a simple todo app as a learning experience. I am modeling each week, only monday through friday, which each have many todo items. My document would look something like this:

```
week = {
    'year': 2012,
    'week': 10,
    'monday': [
        {'task': 'take out the trash', 'effort_points': 1},
        {'task': 'build a house', 'effort_points': 5}
    ],
    'tuesday': [],
    'wednesday': [],
    'thursday': [],
    'friday': []
}
```

So far I have some classes that look something like this (some of it may be pseudo code):

```
class Week
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :year, type: Integer
  field :week, type: Integer
  embeds_one :day, as: :monday
  embeds_one :day, as: :tuesday
  embeds_one :day, as: :wednesday
  embeds_one :day, as: :thursday
  embeds_one :day, as: :friday
end

class Day
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :week
  embeds_many :items
end

class Item
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :day
  field :task
  field :effort_points
end
```

How do I appropriately model these objects using mongoid?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are right with the assumption that fetching one document is more efficient than fetching 15, but you have to keep in mind that a root level document is the unit of quanta you will fetch from db. So if you keep days of week in a single document, you will have to fetch week from db, even if you require a single task.

Another way can be to model day as following:

```
class Week
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :year, type: Integer
  field :week, type: Integer
  embeds_many :days
end

class Day
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :day, type: String
  embedded_in :week
  embeds_many :items

  validates :day, :in => [:monday, tuesday, ....]
end
```

It would have the additional advantage that when you want to see what weeks have some task which are related to coffee, you can query:

```
Week.where("days.items.task" => /coffeee/i).all

# Instead of 
Week.all.or("monday.items.task" => /coffee/i).or("tuesday.items.task: => /coffee/i)...
```

It primarily makes sense because week is the root document, but if you need each day's task independently probably you will make days as a separate collection.

PS: wanted to make it a comment but was too long.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't keep the day and week in the database. I would have one collection/class Task, and put a date field on it. When you want to show what a week's tasks are, just get all the Tasks whose dates are fall in that week.

Comment: Hmm...seems like that would go against the advantages of using Mongo. Since these "Tasks" are such a small amount of data, it would be advantageous to group them together (and embed them into a larger document) so that fetching and displaying the records would be most efficient. I don't know much about Mongo performance, but I would assume that fetching a single document is more efficient than returning 25 documents. What do you think?

Comment: If you have an index on the field that you are using to select them, it's 1 database call and is very fast. The advantage over SQL databases that you are talking about is that you can avoid doing JOINs by keeping related things in a single document. For example, if a task has many "notes", you can keep those in the task and not have to JOIN on a "notes" table to retrieve them.